# sed command not found when run shell in window git bash

Tags: git, shell

I write shell in .sh file and run it in git bash of windows platform. The Git bash command line, it shows "sed command not found", but when i type sed command in the git bash command line, it could display the sed help information and if i run the .sh's sed clause, it executed  properly. I don't know why

Comment: Maybe your script tries to use `PATH` as a private variable, messing up the system's path?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure where the '`sed`' is found when executed directly in the shell:

```
which sed
```

Then echo the path in your script (meaning: add the following line in your script, and run said script):

```
echo $PATH
```

And see if the script, when executed, include a `PATH` which has the folder where `sed` is found.
If not, modify the `PATH` in your script, or use the full path of the `sed` command in your script.